# What is the best way to include template/plugin libraries in meteor-kitchen?

Tags: javascript, meteor-kitchen

I am making custom templates and components on the client side. I need to include a javascript library that only shows up when the component/or template is present, and only once. Is there a good way to make sure it is available when needed and disappears when not?

Answer (score 0):

is your js library packed as npm module?

Are you using react or blaze?

There is template_rendered_code which executes each time component is rendered (you need this one if lib does something with dom).

Most likelly onCreated and onDestroyed (Blaze) or componendWillMount and componendWillUnmount (React) us what you need, but I didn't implemented this in the kitchen (I added this to my Trello tasks).

Comment: I've switched to using the npm modules for the plugins, but I couldn't find a way to include them successfully in the inline and local file versions. Is this a feature? 

I was using React and plan to in the future, but fell back to blaze because of some unimplemented features. Now that I'm switching to the plugin approach I might revert.

Comment: Writing some short examples in your answer as Momin suggests would make for a better Q&A answer.